# Caching web pages using PHP (for offline viewing)

Tags: php, caching

I'm working on a personal project to view web pages offline. The first idea that I came up with is using `file_get_contents` to get the contents of a specific url but this only gets the html and not the assets in that page(css, images, javascript, etc.). So I had to write regex to get the stylesheets and images in the page:

```
$css_pattern = '/\S*\.css"/';
$img_src_pattern = '/src=(?:"|\')?.+\.(?:gif|jpg|png|jpeg)(?:"|\')/';
preg_match_all($css_pattern, $contents, $style_matches);
preg_match_all($img_src_pattern, $contents, $img_matches);
```

This works but there are also images link in the css as well. And I'm still thinking how to deal with those.

There are also projects like `ganon` https://code.google.com/p/ganon/ and simple html parser that might make my life easier but I prefer using regex because I want to learn more about it.

The question is: is there a better way of doing this project? The app will probably have folders in which to save assets and html for each site and it will probably become unwieldy. I've heard of things like manifest file in html5 but I'm not sure if that's possible if you don't own the site. Any ideas? If there's no other way to do this then maybe you can just help me improve the regex that I have above. I basically have to use `str_replace` and `foreach` to get the stylesheets:

```
$stylesheets = array();
foreach($style_matches[0] as $match){
    $stylesheets[] = str_replace(array('href=', '"', "'"), '', $match);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a nontrivial project.  You could parse the HTML for all stylesheets, `<img>` tags, etc. and download them additionally, but there are a whole class of assets that you may miss out on -- namely client side includes.  Any content downloaded through javascript (which is increasingly popular) will be missed.  The only way to get this stuff is to either implement a JS engine in your code, or utilize a small, lightweight web-browser/spider/web-crawler.  I'd being by looking into javascript-aware spiders/web crawlers.

Comment: I didnt get your idea properly. But if you are trying to get assets from someones site then you may use `wget`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I prefer using regex because I want to learn more about it.

Parsing HTML with regex is possible albeit non-trivial. A good introduction is given in the following paper:

- [REX: XML Shallow Parsing with Regular Expressions](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~cameron/REX.html)

The regular expressions used in that paper (REX) are not the ones used in PHP (PCRE), however you should be able to understand it if you're willing to learn, it's similar.

Following what that paper outlines and writing regular expressions in PHP on your own with some nice test-cases should be a real training camp for you digging into regular expressions.

Next to the regular expressions you also need to deal with character encodings which is another field of it's own and then adopting the parser for an encoding (if you do not re-encode before parsing).

If you're looking specifically for an HTML 5 compatible parser, it is specified as part of the HTML 5 "specification", but you can not do it precisely with regular expressions any longer in a sane way (at least as far as I know about it):

- [12.2 Parsing HTML documents — HTML Living Standard — Updated ca. daily](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html)
- [8.2 Parsing HTML documents — HTML5 — A vocabulary and associated APIs for HTML and XHTML W3C Candidate Recommendation 17 December 2012](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing)

For me that type of parsing looks like a large amount of overhead, but peek into the outline of the HTML 5 Parser and you get an idea what you *could* all take care of for HTML parsing nowadays. It seems like those guys and girls really needed to push anything in they could imagine. Actually the following engines/browsers have a HTML 5 Parser:

- [Gecko 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_Parser)
- [Webkit](https://www.webkit.org/blog/1273/the-html5-parsing-algorithm/)
- [Chrome 7](http://chrome.blogspot.de/2010/10/bringing-another-chrome-release-to-you.html) (Webkit)
- [Opera 11.60](http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/2011/12/06/hello-opera-11-60) (Ragnarök)
- [IE10](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/06/html5-parsing-in-ie10.aspx)

From personal experience in the PHP eco-system there are not so many SGML based / "loose" / low-level / tag-soup HTML parsers. If I would write one, I would also use regular expressions for string parsing, the REX shallow parsing article has some good discussion. However I would probably only use such a low-level HTML parser to make any HTML consumable for DOMDocument or some other validation/fixing related stuff and won't use it for further parsing/document abstraction. DOMDocument is pretty powerful especially to gather links which you describe above.

For the rest of your question, you find all the elements you need to bring together outlined in diverse HTTP related RFCs, so you need to decide on your own which link resolving algorithm you want to support and how you re-map the static CSS/image/js files if you save them again. You normally then re-write the HTML as well for which DOMDocument is really handy.

Also you should store some HTTP headers inside the HTML file via the meta element. Especially for the encoding unless you don't re-encode it (which can be useful for offline reading anyway). Some of the more general Q&A suggestions for HTML authoring apply for a static cache as well.

The [html5 manifest file](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) is actually something different. The original server should have supported it. That is likely not the case (or you need to build a parser of it as well and process it). So if you create a mirror, you might want to also point out all static resources that can be stored locally for offline usage. That is some nice idea, I have not yet seen this implemented by tools like wget, so it's probably worth to play with that idea a little.

Instead of the *HTML5 manifest file* you might have also related to one of the following container formats:

- [Mozilla Archive Format - MAFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Archive_Format)
- [MIME HTML - MHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML)
- [Webarchive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webarchive)

Another one of these formats/extensions (here: SingleFile Chrome extension) makes use of the  [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) according to wikipedia, which might be also useful in this context albeit I would not favorite it, I'd say it's better to have an algorithm that is able to re-write URLs to local file-system in a reproduce-able manner so that you can dump multiple HTML files with the same assets without fetching the assets multiple times.